# How to debug custom lint detector

Tags: android, lint

I've written a custom lint detector based off [this](https://github.com/bignerdranch/linette) example repo. I'm trying to debug the detector using the tests provided however when I try to run these tests through Android Studio all I get is an error in the bottom right

> Empty throwable: Unable to determine gradle tasks to execute

Full error:

```
Unable to determine gradle tasks to execute
com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger$EmptyThrowable
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:129)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.DefaultGradleBuilder.build(DefaultGradleBuilder.java:40)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.executeTask(MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.java:258)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.executeTask(MakeBeforeRunTaskProvider.java:86)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$3.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:317)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm unsure what the issue is as I believe I should be able to debug the detectors like this (see [this](https://github.com/a11n/CustomLintRules) source)